# Locate random int after string during with open read()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to open a file, locate and remove a random (below 100) int following a certain word which could be any int depending on the user, the word in question being '-port:'

EDIT: The file blah.txt simply contains the following string: '-port:4'

Atm, the code results in the following error:

"File "p:\Python______________\Automating scripts\demo.py", line 25, in 
f.write(content.replace('-port:'+range, '-port:'))"

The desired outcome for this is to separate the integer from the string, and also then replace the string, removing the integer entirely.

```
range = [1 - 100]
with open ('P:\\blah.txt', 'r+') as f:
    content = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(content.replace('-port:'+range, '-port:'))
    print('\nScript ready')
```

Comment: It seems like that would depend on the contents of the file.  If the posted code solves your problem, why are you here?  If it doesn't, please explain what it does and how that differs from what you want it to do.

Comment: @ScottHunter I don't think `'-port:'+[-99]` ia valid

Comment: Is the use of the use of the `re` package acceptable?

Comment: @ScottHunter The contents, for testing purposes is just a string: -port:4

Comment: @JonSG yes, from the basics I know, re package would be acceptable. Apologies, I'm still a noobie so am researching that now

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to leverage the `re` package and `re.sub()` to pick out the number. I might try:

```py
import re

with open ('P:\\blah.txt', 'r+') as f:
    content = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(re.sub("-port:\d{1,2}", "-port:", content))

print('\nScript ready')
```

Note this is untested, but this seems to work as I anticipate:

```py
import re

content = """
this is a test
of the -port:59 code
"""
print(re.sub("-port:\d{1,2}", "-port:", content))
```

Giving back:

```
this is a test    
of the -port: code
```

Note that this does not guard against a 3 digit port number.